# Mod Rewrite Errors Filling Apache Error Log

Tags: apache-2.4

My Apache error logs are blowing up with the following error but I'm not sure what it means.

```
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433153 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de710a0/initial] init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433191 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de710a0/initial] pass through /
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433242 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433249 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.html
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433275 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.cgi
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433281 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.cgi
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433296 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.pl
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433302 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.pl
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433334 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433340 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.php
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433359 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.xhtml
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433365 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.xhtml
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433383 2015] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.htm
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433388 2015] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 1389] mod_rewrite.c(468): [client 78.136.44.20:46348] 78.136.44.20 - - [commerce1.bigdealsmedia.net/sid#7f6c6df3f658][rid#7f6c6de730a0/subreq] pass through /index.htm
[Fri Aug 21 16:29:02.433409 2015] [autoindex:error] [pid 1389] [client 78.136.44.20:46348] AH01276: Cannot serve directory /var/www/: No matching DirectoryIndex (index.html,index.cgi,index.pl,index.php,index.xhtml,index.htm) found, and server-generated directory index forbidden by Options directive
```

My .htaccess looks like this.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# Rewrite item.php
RewriteRule ^item/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /item.php?item_id=$1 [L]

# Rewrite page.php
RewriteRule ^page/([a-z0-9]+)/.+$ /page.php?page_id=$1 [L]

# Rewrite sitemap.xml
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ sitemap.php [L]

# Remove .php from URL
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# Remove www from URL
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: you have rewrite debugging turned on.

Comment: And I could turn that off by increasing the trace?

Comment: set LogLevel error and RewriteLogLevel 0 in your apache config.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure about using Apache 2.2? The syntax of your events `[rewrite:trace..]` indicates 2.4.

You'll want to find the virtual host definition and see what LogLevel settings are out there. It has to be at least trace2. You likely only want info or higher. See [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632852/how-to-debug-apache-mod-rewrite). Details on the log levels are available [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#loglevel).

Comment: You're right, was 2.4. Sorry about that. Just to clarify, you're saying that the issue is that I'm simply logging too many errors? Thanks for the SO reference, I'm going to check on that now.

Comment: Seems to be trace3: http://pastebin.com/04DhmHqm

Comment: Not errors, tracing you opted in to.